# How to handle mixed datatype values in columns using SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have a question about SQL Server: how to convert scientific notation value to integer values?

We have some bill numbers that were converted to scientific notation. This means they are in the wrong format for bill numbers and should be converted back to regular decimal or numeric format.

I am encountering difficulty converting just those values that have the scientific notation.

The column is of `nvarchar(255)` data type but these values need to be manipulated back into `numeric` or `decimal` data type.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[test]
(
    billno [nvarchar](255) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[test] (billno) VALUES (N'9.2091002309e+012')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[test] (billno) VALUES (NULL)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[test] (billno) VALUES (N'4.0206570015e+019')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[test] (billno) VALUES (N'9.2091002204e+013')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[test] (billno) VALUES (N'SEALED05/10/2016')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[test] (billno) VALUES (N'3101123631')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[test] (billno) VALUES (N'57108')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[test] (billno) VALUES (N'9.1108000026e+014')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[test] (billno) VALUES (N'97033429A')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[test] (billno) VALUES (N'5.0846721402e+017')
```

I have tried like this, but if I run this query:

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
       WHEN billno like '%E+%'
          THEN CAST(CAST(CAST(billno AS FLOAT) AS numeric) AS NVARCHAR(255))
          ELSE billno 
       END expectedresult,
    billno
FROM
    test324.dbo.test 
WHERE
    billno NOT IN ('4.0206570015e+019', '5.0846721402e+017')
```

then this is the results:

```
expectedresult  |billno
----------------+------------------
9209100230900   |9.2091002309e+012
92091002204000  |9.2091002204e+013
SEALED05/10/2016|   SEALED05/10/2016
3101123631      |3101123631
57108           |57108
911080000260000 |9.1108000026e+014
97033429A       |97033429A
170668650010000 |1.7066865001e+014
```

If I run this query:

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
       WHEN billno LIKE '%E+%'
          THEN CAST(CAST(CAST(billno AS FLOAT) AS numeric) AS NVARCHAR(255))
          ELSE billno 
    END test,
    billno
FROM
    test
```

Then I get an error:

> Msg 8115, Level 16, State 6, Line 2
>   Arithmetic overflow error converting float to data type numeric.

I need to get all records related output information. Can you please tell me how to do this in SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server 2012+ you could use:

```
SELECT TRY_CAST(TRY_CAST(billno AS FLOAT(54)) AS BIGINT)
FROM test;
```

Anyway you should fix how application saves values. Storing them as `FLOAT` is bad idea (`FLOAT` is not precise datatype).